# Import modules Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been working a while on creating a probability calculator with a Tkinter GUI.
I'm much better at maths than at python, so please be kind :)

I have a Tkinter GUI were I can select a user. The userlist is populated from a csv file. I've created the GUI so that when I select a user, straight away extra information get pulled out of the same csv file.

What I want to achieve is that when I run my GUI, filled called `inputTK`the result of the `calculate`function inside the `inputTK`file get pushed to the `tennisGameProbability` script and is set in the `service_hold`field inside `tennisGameProbability`.

When I than push the `Run` button I want the result of the `tennisGameProbability`displayed inside my Tkinter GUI.

When I run "inputTK" I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Magali\Desktop\Tennis\inputTK.py", line 85, in resultsgame
    print tennisGameProbability.gameProb()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gameProb'
```

How can I solve this?

> My scripts
>
> inputTk --> this is my GUI script

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import csv
import tennisGameProbability

frame = Tk()


def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value_player1c = float(v1player1.get())/100
        value_player1d = float(v2player1.get())/100
        value_player1e = float(v3player1.get())/100
        result_player_1.set((((value_player1c * value_player1d)-(value_player1c * value_player1e)) + value_player1e))
        return ((((value_player1c * value_player1d)-(value_player1c * value_player1e)) + value_player1e))
    except ValueError:
        pass

def amount_of_sets():
    return v6player1.get()


b1player1 = StringVar()
v1player1 = StringVar()
v2player1 = StringVar()
v3player1 = StringVar()
v6player1 = StringVar()
result_player_1 = StringVar()
result = StringVar()

aplayer1 = Label(frame, text="Player 1", font="{Bodoni MT} 10 bold").grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=15)
bplayer1 = Label(frame, text="Player Name").grid(row=9, column=1, sticky='w')
cplayer1 = Label(frame, text="1st Service Percentage:").grid(row=10, column=1, sticky='w')
ccplayer1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v1player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=10, column=2)
dplayer1 = Label(frame, text="Points Won on 1st Serve: ").grid(row=11, column=1, sticky='w')
ddplayer1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v2player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=11, column=2)
eplayer1 = Label(frame, text="Points Won on 2nd serve:").grid(row=12, column=1, sticky='w')
eeplayer1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v3player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=12, column=2)

hplayer1 = Label(frame, text="Number of Sets:").grid(row=7, column=1)
hhplayer1 = Entry(frame, text="value", textvariable=v6player1, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=7, column=2)

myresult = Label(frame, textvariable=result, justify='center', width=10).grid(row=3, column=2)


f = open('testtennis.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
players_names = []
for row in csv_f:
    players_names.append(row[0])


def newselection(event):
    return player1()

box_value = StringVar()
box = ttk.Combobox(frame, textvariable=box_value, justify='center')
box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", newselection)
box['values'] = players_names
box.current()
box.grid(column=2, row=9)


def player1():
    with open("testtennis.csv") as fh:
        for row in fh:
            if (box_value.get()) in row:
                player_name = row[0:row.find(',')]
                row = row.replace(player_name+',', '')
                firstservice = row[0:row.find(",")]
                row = row.replace(firstservice+',', '')
                points_firstserve = row[0:row.find(",")]
                row = row.replace(points_firstserve+',', '')
                points_secondserve = row[0:row.find(",")]
                row.replace(points_secondserve+',', '')
                v1player1.set(firstservice)
                v2player1.set(points_firstserve)
                v3player1.set(points_secondserve)
                return box_value.get()

def oneclick():
    return calculate()

def resultsgame():
    print tennisGameProbability.gameProb()


run = ttk.Button(frame, text='Run', command=resultsgame)
run.grid(column=1, row=25, columnspan=4, ipadx=50, pady=25)

frame.geometry("1000x500+100+100")
mainloop()
```

> tennisGameProbability --> this script runs my probability calculations
>   and the results of this calculation needs to be displayed in my GUI

```
import inputTK

service_hold = inputTK.oneclick()
points_server = 0
points_receiver = 0


def fact(x):
    if x in [0, 1]:
        return 1
    r = 1
    for a in range(1, (x+1)):
        r = r*a
    return r


def ch(a, b):
    return fact(a)/(fact(b)*fact(a-b))


def gameOutcome(s, a, b):
    return ch((a+b), a)*(s**a)*((1-s)**b)*s


def gameProb(s=service_hold, v=points_server, w=points_receiver):
    if v >= 4 and (v-w) >= 2:
        return 1
    elif w >= 4 and (w-v) >= 2:
        return 0
    else:
        pass
    while True:
        if (v+w) > 6:
            v -= 1
            w -= 1
        else:
            break
        if w == 0:
            w0 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 0)
    else:
        w0 = 0
    if w <= 1:
        w15 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 1-w)
    else:
        w15 = 0
    if w <= 2:
        w30 = gameOutcome(s, 3-v, 2-w)
    else:
        w30 = 0
    if v == 4:
        wAd, lAd = s, 0
        d = 1-s
    elif w == 4:
        wAd, lAd = 0, 1-s
        d = s
    else:
        wAd, lAd = 0, 0
        a = 3 - v
        b = 3 - w
        d = ch((a+b), a)*(s**a)*((1-s)**b)
    if v <= 2:
        l30 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 2-v)
    else:
        l30 = 0
    if v <= 1:
        l15 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 1-v)
    else:
        l15 = 0
    if v == 0:
        l0 = gameOutcome((1-s), 3-w, 0)
    else:
        l0 = 0
    denom = s**2 + (1-s)**2
    wd = (d*(s**2))/denom
    ld = (d*((1-s)**2))/denom
    win = w0 + w15 + w30 + wd + wAd
    lose = l0 + l15 + l30 + ld + lAd
    return win
print gameProb()
```

Comment: You have a circular import. Restructure your code so you don't have both modules needing to import each other.

Comment: @user2357112, and what do I have to restructure? Could you give me some tips and hints?

Comment: Your `tennisGameProbability` script importing `inputTk`. Here how it works: `inputTk` line 4 imports `tennisGameProbability` and when it's imported the first line imports `inputTk` back and goes to the line 4 and imports.... see now?

Comment: I think as a rule of thumb, your business logic and GUI code should be completely separate. Your GUI can create an instance of `tennisGameProbability`, and then it can ask it to return values. `tennisGameProbability` should never need to import `inputTK`.

Comment: @Leuthus, yes, I see it now, thank you, but how do I import than the calculation function form inputTK into tennisGameProbability?

Comment: @Wouter Separate the logic to an other script as Hobbes suggested above

Comment: @Leuthus, so I create an other script that collects the info from my inputTK and puts it in tennisGameProbability and than again an other script to get the results from tennisGameProbability to my inputTK?

Comment: From the looks of it, `calculate` should be within `tennisGameProbability`, and your `inputTk` will call it with the appropriate arguments as required. You shouldn't need a third file for this.

Comment: @Hobbes, yes, that worked, thank you very much. But how do I get now the outcomes of the tennisGameProbability displayed in inputTK?